# How extract description in a google search using python?

Tags: python, html, google-search

I want to extract the description from the google search,
now I have this code:

```
from urlparse import urlparse, parse_qs
import urllib

from lxml.html import fromstring
from requests import get


    url='https://www.google.com/search?q=Gotham'
    raw = get(url).text
    pg = fromstring(raw)
    v=[]
    for result in pg.cssselect(".r a"):
      url = result.get("href")
      if url.startswith("/url?"):
         url = parse_qs(urlparse(url).query)['q']
      print url[0]
```

that extract urls related with the search, how can I extract the description that appears under the url?

Comment: You should be careful about programmatic queries to Google. Do it enough, and you will get blocked for violating their Terms of Service.

I can recommend you use their Custom Search API.

Answer (score 1):

You can scrape Google Search Description Website using [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) web scraping library.

To collect information from all pages you can use "pagination" with `while True` loop. The while loop is an endless loop, the exit from which in our case is the presence of a switch button to the next page, namely the CSS selector ".d6cvqb a[id=pnnext]":

```py
if soup.select_one('.d6cvqb a[id=pnnext]'):
        params["start"] += 10
else:
    break
```

You can use CSS selectors search to find all the information you need (description, title, etc.)  which are easy to identify on the page using a [SelectorGadget](https://selectorgadget.com/) Chrome extension (*not always work perfectly if the website is rendered via JavaScript*).

Make sure you're using [request headers](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers) [`user-agent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/User_agent) to act as a "real" user visit. Because default `requests` `user-agent` is [`python-requests`](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814) and websites understand that it's most likely a script that sends a request. [Check what's your `user-agent`](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent/).

Check code in [online IDE](https://replit.com/@denisskopa/scrape-description-google-bs4#main.py).

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, json, lxml

# https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls
params = {
    "q": "gotham",       # query
    "hl": "en",          # language
    "gl": "us",          # country of the search, US -> USA
    "start": 0,          # number page by default up to 0
    #"num": 100          # parameter defines the maximum number of results to return.
}

# https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

page_num = 0

website_data = []

while True:
    page_num += 1
    print(f"page: {page_num}")
        
    html = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search", params=params, headers=headers, timeout=30)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')
    
    for result in soup.select(".tF2Cxc"):
        website_name = result.select_one(".yuRUbf a")["href"]
        try:
          description = result.select_one(".lEBKkf").text
        except:
          description = None
                    
        website_data.append({
              "website_name": website_name,
              "description": description  
        })
      
    if soup.select_one('.d6cvqb a[id=pnnext]'):
        params["start"] += 10
    else:
        break

print(json.dumps(website_data, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Example output:

```json
[
    {
    "website_name": "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3749900/",
    "description": "The show follows Jim as he cracks strange cases whilst trying to help a young Bruce Wayne solve the mystery of his parents' murder. It seemed each week for a ..."
  },
  {
    "website_name": "https://www.netflix.com/watch/80023082",
    "description": "When the key witness in a homicide ends up dead while being held for questioning, Gordon suspects an inside job and seeks details from an old friend."
  },
  {
    "website_name": "https://www.gothamknightsgame.com/",
    "description": "Gotham Knights is an open-world, action RPG set in the most dynamic and interactive Gotham City yet. In either solo-play or with one other hero, ..."
  },
  # ...
]
```

---

Or you can also use [Google Search Engine Results API](https://serpapi.com/search-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with the free plan.
The difference is that it will bypass blocks (including CAPTCHA) from Google, no need to create the parser and maintain it.

Code example:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
from urllib.parse import urlsplit, parse_qsl
import json, os

params = {
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"), # serpapi key
  "engine": "google",              # serpapi parser engine
  "q": "gotham",                   # search query
  "num": "100"                     # number of results per page (100 per page in this case)
  # other search parameters: https://serpapi.com/search-api#api-parameters
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)      # where data extraction happens

organic_results_data = []
page_num = 0

while True:
    results = search.get_dict()    # JSON -> Python dictionary
    
    page_num += 1
    
    for result in results["organic_results"]:
        organic_results_data.append({
            "title": result.get("title"),
            "snippet": result.get("snippet")   
        })
    
    if "next_link" in results.get("serpapi_pagination", []):
        search.params_dict.update(dict(parse_qsl(urlsplit(results.get("serpapi_pagination").get("next_link")).query)))
    else:
        break
    
print(json.dumps(organic_results_data, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Output:

```json
[
   {
    "title": "Gotham (TV Series 2014–2019) - IMDb",
    "snippet": "The show follows Jim as he cracks strange cases whilst trying to help a young Bruce Wayne solve the mystery of his parents' murder. It seemed each week for a ..."
  },
  {
    "title": "Gotham (TV series) - Wikipedia",
    "snippet": "Gotham is an American superhero crime drama television series developed by Bruno Heller, produced by Warner Bros. Television and based on characters from ..."
  },
  # ...
]
```